# Notation of the Optimal action value function $q^*$

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory

In reinforcement learning, when we talk about the optimal action value function, does the equality of this picture is true? 
$$
q_*(s,a) = q_{\pi*}(s,a)
$$

In my book, I see both notations and I want to make sure that it's equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the notation?